# Dynamically giving nested lists to itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have 6 lists: `pool_x, pool_y, pool_z, global_x, global_y, global_z` and one set `unique_points`. I am using `itertools` to make cartesian product of these lists is a certain way:

```
        for element in itertools.product(pool_x, pool_y, pool_z):
            unique_points.add(element)
        for element in itertools.product(global_x, pool_y, pool_z):
            unique_points.add(element)
        for element in itertools.product(pool_x, global_y, pool_z):
            unique_points.add(element)
        for element in itertools.product(pool_x, pool_y, global_z):
            unique_points.add(element)
```

But as you can see this is hard coded way. The above code is for 3 Dimensions. In 2 Dimensions: my lists are only 4 i.e. `pool_x, pool_y, global_x, global_y` and the code becomes like this:

```
        for element in itertools.product(pool_x, pool_y):
            unique_points.add(element)
        for element in itertools.product(pool_x, global_y):
            unique_points.add(element)
        for element in itertools.product(global_x, pool_y):
            unique_points.add(element)
```

**Question** now I want to scale this code to *any dimension*. For this, so far I have achieved is to make nested lists: `pools` (including pool_x, pool_y, pool_z depending upon any dimension) and `globals` (including global_x, global_y etc.). Then, the first cartesian product (that is in between pools) can be achieved by this:

```
        for element in itertools.product(*pools):
            unique_points.add(element)
```

But how to make all cartesian products between pools and globals just like previous code is doing for 2 Dimension and 3 Dimension? The correctness can be verified if new dynamic code gives us same pairs as the above hardcoded code is giving us. OR any other way to do this is also welcomed.

Comment: So, you want ever product of ever *combination* of some particular size...?

Comment: Think like point as a vector in coordinate plane eg (1,2,3). First number will be x-axis, second will be y-axis and third will be z-axis. All I want is to make all possible combination of these points by making the cartesian product of pools and globals

Comment: You already got how to do it: put all of the lists into a larger list, and take the `product` of that.

Comment: @Prune if I pull all lists into a larger list, the length of vector would be huge. But the length of vector should be equal to dimensions

Comment: @prune this question is different from the one you associated its similarity with. Please reopen it. That question does not work with nested lists. I have checked and commented there too

Comment: I can see where you might not extract your solution from the duplicate I chose -- it doesn't touch the `chain` operator you need.  Use those keywords to find what I hope is your solution.

Comment: a simple working example in shape of answer would be appreciated @Prune

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out answer by myself.

```
        for i in range(self.dimensions):
            temp_pools = list(self.pools)  # make new list of pools so that original pools stays untouched
            temp_pools[i] = self.globals[i]  # <= main thing
            for element in itertools.product(*temp_pools):
                self.unique_points.add(element)
```

in this way, all combinations of `pools` and `globals` can be achieved no matter which dimension is given.